# How many regions of India can you realistically visit in 1 month without rushing?

Tags: india

I am planning a trip in India around June 2015.

The best trips I have done so far, were those where I took the time to visit a place thoroughly without feeling rushed.

I'd like to stay about 1 month in India. I know the country is huge and it's impossible to visit all of it during this amount of time. This is why I would like to focus on a few regions.

My areas of interest that I want to focus on are

1. mostly photography, food and nature.
2. I am a big fan of Indian cuisine and I would like to experiment as much as possible.
3. Also, I plan on taking a lot of photos in India.
4. Be it rural, urban or in the nature. I am fairly in shape, so I also plan on doing some trekking to see nature spots.
5. I also am interested in visiting temples, but my trip won't revolve around this.

From your experiences, can you please tell me about regions I should visit to experience India at its best ? Pointers as to which regions are best to visit during summer time would be appreciated.

Comment: Remember, some travellers think 'rushing' is spending 1 month in a city, let alone country.  Also please look at the [help], as asking subjective questions like 'which regions are best' is usually frowned upon. Cheers!

Comment: What are your travel objectives? Culture, adventure, food, luxury, religious, etc.? Based on that, I can suggest pointers as to where you might want to focus the majority of your time

Comment: For me, one month is not enough time to visit even a single city.

Comment: Edited to add interests.

Comment: Check out Indianrail Pass - http://www.indianrail.gov.in/international_Tourist.html That would help you plan your trip

Comment: In India contain 29 States and this 29 States Show 29 type of views. 
I can suggest some place